# How to create a circular rainbow in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, gradient

I am wondering, how do I create this radial, rainbow gradient in Inkscape?

[image]

This is my attempt:

[image]

1. I create a circle, with 3 equal portions. I expect to handle these 3 portions separately through setting the gradient, and finally remove the borders if any.
2. I think the problem is how I change the gradient. The original image is able to make the gradient so smoothly and radially, but somehow mine one just doesn't make it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where are you stuck?  This site follows a Q&A format, rather than a tutorial one.

Comment: Hi Manly, ya you are right. i will put those attempts into words by today.

Comment: @Manly I have added my attempts.

Comment: I don't use Inkscape, but if I were to do this in Illustrator, I wouldn't create the circle in three steps.  You should create only one circular shape and instead alter your gradient.

Comment: @Manly you are right. Only 1 circle is enough. And mesh gradient is the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into mesh gradients. These allow you to set a gradient in 2d space, so you can place different colors at different points.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning something new to me. Ya i think that's a great direction to start off. Let me try out and will update you here again.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what i am looking for! And i don't need partition the circle at all!

Comment: have a look at the details in the inkscape wiki: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Mesh_Gradients